# constructors not allowed a return type (Generic Linked List)

Tags: c++, templates, linked-list

I am trying to make a Generic Linked list in C++ using templates. But i am getting this error 'GenericNode::{ctor}': constructors not allowed a return type through which i can't possibly know what am i doing wrong?
PS. i have also gone through other posts here on Stack Overflow which says that the error is due to the missing semi-colon after the class definition but i think i don't have a 'missing semi-colon' case. Any help?

Code :

GenericLinkedList.h :

```
#pragma once

template <typename Datatype>
class GenericNode {
    Datatype T;
    GenericNode *next;

public:

    GenericNode() {}

    GenericNode(Datatype T);

};

template<typename Datatype>
void GenericNode<Datatype>::GenericNode(Datatype data) {
    T = data;
}

template <typename Datatype>
class GenericLinkedList {

    GenericNode *Data;

public:

    GenericLinkedList() {
        Data = NULL;
    }

    int isEmpty();
    void addDataAtFront(Datatype data);
    void addDataAtEnd(Datatype data);
    void print();

};

template <typename Datatype>
int GenericLinkedList<Datatype>::isEmpty() {
    return Data == NULL;
}

template <typename Datatype>
void GenericLinkedList<Datatype>::addDataAtFront(Datatype data) {
    GenericNode *newNode, *tmpNode;
    newNode = new Node;
    newNode->T = data;
    newNode->next = NULL;

    if (Data == NULL) {
        Data = newNode;
    }

    else {
        tmpNode = Data;
        Data = newNode;
        Data->next = tmpNode;

    }

}

template <typename Datatype>
void GenericLinkedList<Datatype>::addDataAtEnd(Datatype data) {
    GenericNode *newNode, *tmpNode;
    newNode = new Node;
    newNode->T = data;
    newNode->next = NULL;

    if (Data == NULL) {
        Data = newNode;
    }

    else {
        tmpNode = Data;
        while (tmpNode->next != NULL) {
            tmpNode = tmpNode->next;
        }

        tmpNode->next = newNode;

    }

}

template <typename Datatype>
void GenericLinkedList<Datatype>::print() {
    GenericNode tmpNode;
    tmpNode = Data;
    for (tmpNode;tmpNode != NULL;tmpNode = tmpNode->next) {
        cout << tmpNode->T << " ";
    }
}
```

.cpp :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include "GenericLinkedList.h"
using namespace std;

int main() {

    GenericLinkedList<int> T;
    T.addDataAtFront(5);
    T.addDataAtEnd(6);
    T.addDataAtFront(4);
    T.print();

    _getch();
}
```

Comment: `void` is redundant.

Comment: @songyuanyao Not redundant, just not allowed when defining constructors.

Comment: oh my god! i feel so stupid :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
template<typename Datatype>
void GenericNode<Datatype>::GenericNode(Datatype data) {
    T = data;
}
```

You write the return type void. It's a constructor.

Comment: yeah, a dumb mistake by me! :/ anyways Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

void GenericNode::GenericNode(Datatype data)
remove void its a constructor. Constructors don't return and dont have a return type.